# Special character in URL ignored by browsers

Tags: url, browser, special-characters, url-parameters

I have a simple website (using java) which has login and reset password page. In the reset password page, when a valid email is given, an email is sent to the user with a url for the reset password page with a token which I generate by encrypting certain data.

I get the email with the correct url and the correct token. But the token contains a special character "+" (Sometimes multiple times. But so far I have seen only this as the special character).

But when I click on the link, in Firefox the "+" character is turned to blank space and in Chrome, IE and safari the "+" character is changed to "%20".

Since i'm passing this token to validate the user as valid, to reset his password, I'm unable to decrypt it. So even for a valid user the reset password is failing.

I have put a temporary fix by doing a string replace to black spaces and "%20" back to "+". But since this doesn't look like a long term solution, can anyone suggest a more permanent fix for this issue?

example

```
Original : http://examplewebsite/resetPassword?token=abcedfg+abcedf+g

Firefox  : http://examplewebsite/resetPassword?token=abcedfg abcedf g

Others   : http://examplewebsite/resetPassword?token=abcedfg%20abcedf%20g
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using PHP as programming language, use this function to decode URL 
urldecode ($url);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which language you are working , every language has url encoder and decoders use them, basically + and some ther characters get encoded into %20% and other values, you need a url decoder for converting back before decrypting it.

For java , refer [UrlDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)

Sample code :-

```
   URLDecoder.decode("special+chars%3A+%26%25*+", "UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

`+` is a special character that encodes space in URLs. To have it stand for itself you have to encode it as %2B.

The standard library in your programming language probably has functions for URL encoding, for example URLEncoder class in Java.

Answer (score 1):

For total uniformity across the browsers, you'll want to pass your token string though a URLeconder, then do a URL decode on the query string on the receiving end.

In php it's: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php